# Получение ключей и значений из словаря в виде списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции

Замечательный класс `OrderedDict` из модуля `collections`, единственный  способ упорядочить словарь. Но итоговый результат будет вида `OrderedDict([('Италия', 14), ('Аргентина', 6), ('Бразилия', 2), ('Чехия', 1), .......])`

Операции над списками этот тип объектов не поддерживает.

Вопрос: можно ли вытащить данные (например срез) или хотя бы сбросить "`OrderedDict`"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно получить данные словаря (любого словаря, не только `OrderedDict` - т.е. просто `dict`, `defaultdict` и прочее) в виде списка, обратившись к методу `.items()` словаря, а потом преобразовав полученный итератор к списку. На примере данных из вопроса:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([('Италия', 14), ('Аргентина', 6), ('Бразилия', 2), ('Чехия', 1)])
print(list(d.items()))
# Вывод: [('Италия', 14), ('Аргентина', 6), ('Бразилия', 2), ('Чехия', 1)]
```

Comment: спасибо!!!11111